# AWS Amplify react white screen problem using figma UI

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, figma

I created some UI components in figma, then loaded them into AWS amplify studio.

I used the command line to create a blank new react project. I started a local development server to view the starter template for react.

After I changed the index and app file to use the aws amplify UI components (after using the pull command from AWS), I get a white screen when trying to add any components.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Hi, is it same on local development?

Comment: Hi, yes I was using local development and couldn't get it to load.
This blog post is similar to what I used to set it up: https://sbstjn.com/blog/react-figma-amplify-studio-example/

Comment: Update: It seems like it wasn't loading properly because the component I was trying to add was a collection.
I added traditional components and they loaded properly. 
Perhaps when doing local development, you need to load in dummy data in order for the collection to show.